# UWP ListView/GridView DragItems results to Catastrophic Failure

Tags: c#, uwp, drag-and-drop

We are developing an UWP App that needs the ability to drag items from one GridView to another.
While testing this functionality we encountered multiple catastrophic failures 0x80000FFFF.

[image: Screenshot of catastrophic failure]

After almost 2 days of research we were not able to find a solution for our problem. 
We found out that these failures happen, when there's an ItemTemplate set for the GridView the item is dragged from.

Even trying out the official drag-drop sample provided by Microsoft “XamlDragAndDrop”,(https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/XamlDragAndDrop), when you drag the items in Scenario1 from the source ListView to the target ListView (~30-50) times, you will encounter the failure as well.

Has someone else encountered this problem before? We would be super grateful for any advice!

Our developing machines run Windows 10 Enterprise, Version 1803, OS build 17134.285.

Opened an issue on the official GitHub repo.
https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/977

I recorded a small video of the sample crashing.
https://1drv.ms/v/s!AiZ-jksNqbXLi9kZPPfSeGmQr_YeHg

We managed the get the native trace here.
[image: Native trace]

When running in release mode its crashing earlier, and also when the redraw function is turned on in the display heatmap section.

Comment: you should probably open an issue on the samples repo as well and let them know tht even official samples are causing the issue and link this stackoverflow question to that issue there as well.

Comment: Could you have a try with the sample on other devices? I have tried the sample again, but there is no any exceptions. I could not reproduce the issue on my device with the same device OS version. Could you provide more info to help me reproduce this issue?

Comment: Hey! I can reproduce this problem on a Parallels VM running on a 2017 MacBook Pro running Windows 10 Enterprise 1803. It takes about 70 drags most of the time. Interestingly, when enabling "Redraw" in the "Display Heatmaps" section the problem usually occurs earlier.

Comment: why is the dragged thing stuck?

Comment: The solution will be released on the next Windows Update Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 18262 (19H1)  release of may.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Raymond Chen](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/977#issuecomment-441157693) this is a ***plataform specific*** problem which was solved in the Windows 10 May 2019 update.

So the solution is: update your version of the windows to the latest.
Find out **[here](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2019/05/21/how-to-get-the-windows-10-may-2019-update/)** how you can update it.

[Windows 10 May 2019 (What's new)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-insider/at-home/whats-new-wip-at-home-19h1)

[Windows 10 May 2019 changelog](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-19h1-changelog)